# Simple PHP Controller, any issues with this code?

Tags: php, controller

I'm trying to build a really simple php controller page for a small site.  Here is what I have so far.  It seems to work well.  Are there any issues I might be missing with doing it this way?

```
$page = $_GET['p'];

switch ($page)
{
case "":
    ob_start();
    include "inc/home.php";
    $content = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    break;
case $page:
    $page = str_replace("/", "", $page);
    if (file_exists("inc/".$page.".php"))
    {
       ob_start();
       include "inc/".$page.".php";
       $content = ob_get_contents();
       ob_end_clean();
    }
    else
       include "inc/404.php";
    break;
}

include("inc/header.php");

echo $content;

include("inc/footer.php");
```

UPDATE:  Here is the final code based on comments that works well.

```
<?php

$page = (isset( $_GET['p']) && !empty($_GET['p'])) ? $_GET['p'] : 'home';

if( preg_match( '/[^a-z]/i', $page))
{
    $page = '404';
}

if( !file_exists( "inc/".$page.".php"))
{
    $page = '404';
}

ob_start();
include("inc/header.php");
include("inc/".$page.".php");
include("inc/footer.php");

?>
```

Comment: Instead of `case $page:` (which is really weird syntax, by the way), you should use `default:`, although I really don't see the point of using a switch statement here.

Comment: `$page` is susceptible to [local file inclusion](http://hakipedia.com/index.php/Local_File_Inclusion). Also, there's no output wrapper around the 404 include - Not sure if that's intentional or not.

Comment: Thanks for the input, what could be used instead of a switch?

Comment: Doesn't the $page = str_replace("/", "", $page); prevent local file inclusion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your entire script can be rewritten as follows:

```
$page = ( isset( $_GET['p']) && !empty( $_GET['p'])) ? $_GET['p'] : 'home';

// Only allow alphabetic characters in a user supplied page
if( preg_match( '/[^a-z]/i', $page))
{
    $page = '404';
}

if( !file_exists( "inc/".$page.".php"))
{
    $page = '404';
}

include("inc/header.php");
include("inc/".$page.".php");
include("inc/footer.php");
```

However, this is also no longer susceptible to [Local File Inclusion](http://hakipedia.com/index.php/Local_File_Inclusion), as `$page` is restricted to only alphabetic characters, and the script will show the 404 page if anything else is submitted.

It's also more efficient as its not using output buffering.

Comment: just make sure to only put loadable page files in the inc folder.  It might be better to change that to pages/$page.php

Comment: I am having trouble getting this to work for a page that has: 
header("location: index.php?p=newpage");

The same page loads ok in the original version. Wondering why that is?

Comment: Ahh, missed that.  Works great now.  Thanks, I think I will use your version of the controller, more secure and less code :)

Comment: @markf - You're welcome `:)` - If my post answered your question, please consider marking it as accepted.

Comment: Actually, I am getting a headers already sent message now that I've populated the header.php file on that page with the header redirect. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to put your `header("location: index.php?p=newpage");` before you output anything, which includes calling `include("inc/header.php");`

Comment: So then there is no way of ever using a header redirect in one of the pages? Header.php needs to be part of every page, thats where the template will be.  In my original version it worked, Im just not sure why it wont work in your version or how to make it work.

Comment: If you need to do a header redirect in an included page, use output buffering like you did in your example code.

Comment: I added buffering on this part and now it seems to work.  Thanks again.

ob_start();
include("inc/header.php");
include("inc/".$page.".php");
include("inc/footer.php");